# How to integrate Codeceptjs with Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, puppeteer, codeceptjs

Am using Puppeteer helper in creating my page object model end to end tests. I want to integrate my tests with Jenkins so I can schedule my run. Can you guys please help me with the steps?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have created an end to end test and have created a repository for the same in bit bucket. Was going through tutorials on how to integrate the bit bucket url with Jenkins.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend you to use blue ocean plugin in Jenkins.
you can make a pipeline based on the repository in the bit bucket.

https://jenkins.io/doc/book/blueocean/creating-pipelines/

then your codeceptjs project get installed in Jenkins.
and make multiple stages for following steps.

1. npm install (I think you have package.json in your codeceptjs
   folder)
2. run test with codeceptjs command.
3. make a report(test result) and let it be shown in Jenkins (I like allure report and you can download Jenkins-allure plugin without restarting jenkins)

sorry that I can write the full details here. 
you can comment me if you have further question.

Comment: I just started using puppeteer and puppetry to create some tests fast, and I also like the allure report, but I'm having trouble finding support on how to make allure reports more useful. For example, my tests take screenshots, and they are getting stored in a temp file but, I can't figure out how to have allure pull them in to be reviewed as part of the report. I am also interested in eventually incorporating into jenkins, I very much appreciate your guidance here.